# Python - is there a more effective method to find these parameter values?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, lxml

currently using beautifulsoup to find this a tag which y value return:

and

```
Longitude = re.search("Longitude\=[\d]+\.[\d]+", str(y)).group(0)
```

returns "Longitude=27.2115500"

is there a  better way to return the values of BusinessName, Address, Latitude, Longitude, and AdvertiserID, where the value of y is:

```
<a href="http://maps.website.com/default.aspx?AdvertiserID=ZZ_13130030_5182_000761&amp;Latitude=-18.1320800&amp;Longitude=17.2115500&amp;BusinessName=ACME Ltd&amp;Address=55 Nowhere Rd In This Town&amp;telno=&amp;advertiser=location&amp;routeType=to&amp;origincoords=-18.1320800|17.2115500#tabs-2;" 
onclick="dcsMultiTrack('DCSext._mainreq','','DCSext.linktype','get directions','DCSext.linkplace','','DCSext.linkvalue','','DCSext.show_listingId','ZZ_13130030_5182_000761_8378972_IYMX','DCSext.show_zoningUsed','0','DCSext.show_resultNumber','2')" target="_blank">Get directions</a>'''
```

Comment: error in my post.. should now show the value in the tag,,,

sorry..i'm still new...

Answer (score 2):

You can read the `href` property of the tag with: `href = tag["href"]`, then get the parameters:

```
   from urlparse import urlparse
   o = urlparse(href)
   params = dict(query.split("=") for query in o.query.split("&"))
```

then you can get the value with:

`params["Longitude"], params["BusinessName"]` , etc

Comment: i'm stuck on this one again....when BusinessName contain words like 'B&B' or 'X&Y'

any suggestions?

Comment: Solved... the following is less sensitive

o = dict(parse_qsl(urlparse(href)[4]))

Answer (score 2):

Use [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html)

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> the_url = """
http://maps.website.com/default.aspx?AdvertiserID=ZZ_13130030_5182_000761&amp;Latitude=-18.1320800&amp;Longitude=17.2115500&amp;BusinessName=ACME Ltd&amp;Address=55 Nowhere Rd In This Town&amp;telno=&amp;advertiser=location&amp;routeType=to&amp;origincoords=-18.1320800|17.2115500#tabs-2;
"""
>>> query_string = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(the_url)[4])
>>> query_string['AdvertiserID'][0]
```

Comment: get an err = query_string = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(the_url)[4])
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'parse_qs'

Comment: I'm also stuck on this one...  

using Python 2.7.3 keep on getting the error above...

Comment: Make sure you are using [`urllparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) and not [`urllib.urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.5:

```
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'http://tupagina.com/?var1=6e5d8&var2=40'
#url = str(request.get_full_path())
parsed = urlparse(url)
qs = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
var1 = qs['var1'][0]
var2 = qs['var2'][0]
```